# Mean absoluate error of each tree in Random Forest

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, classification, weka, random-forest

I am using the evaluation class of weka for the the mean absolute error of each generated tree in random forest. The explanation says that "Refers to the error of the predicted values for numeric classes, and the error of the predicted probability distribution for nominal classes."

Can someone explain it in easy words or probably with an exammple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean absolute error is an indication of how close your predictions are, on average, to the actual values of the test data.

For numerical classes this is easy to think about.
Example:

> True values: {0, 1, 4}
>   Predicted values: {1, 3, 1}
>   Differences: {-1, -2, 3} (subtract predicted from true)
>   Absolute differences: {1, 2, 3}
>   Mean Absolute Difference: (1+2+3)/3 = 2

For nominal classes a prediction is no longer a single value, but rather the probability distribution of the instance belonging to the different possible classes.  The provided example will have two classes.
Example:

> Notation: [0.5, 0.5] indicates an instance with 50% chance of belonging to class Y, 50% chance of belonging to class X.
>
> True distributions: { [0,1] , [1,0] }
>   Predicted distributions: { [0.25, 0.75], [1, 0] }
>   Differences: { [-0.25, 0.25], [0, 0] }
>   Absolute differences: { (0.25 + 0.25)/2, (0 + 0)/2 } = {0.25, 0}
>   Mean absolute difference: (0.25 + 0)/2 = 0.125

[You can double check my explanation by visiting the source code for Weka's evaluation class.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.6/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.java#Evaluation.meanAbsoluteError%28%29)
Also as a side note, I believe the mean absolute difference reported by Weka for random forest is for the forest as a whole, not the individual trees.

Comment: Could you also explain how Weka calculates the predicted distributions for nominal classes?